# Order in which subscribers notify in Knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I have a table with rows.
Each time I click a row, the viewmodel notifies it to other viewmodels by using a **subscriber**.

At the same time, I have icons on each row. Whenever I click on an icon I have a `click` binding to a function in one of my viewmodels.

Now, the problem arises when I try to get any value from the row in the `click` binded function.

It seems the subscription gets fired later than the click function. Therefore when I'm on the click function I can not access the data from the row yet.

I solved it by padding the row `data` directly in the click function. But then I want to be able to access the click function from outside the row, lets say, in a fixed or absolute element in my DOM, and therefore I won't be able to pass the `row` data from its `click` binding. That's why I'm using a **subscriber** that gets fired on row select.

My question is. How do we know when the subscriber is going to be fired? 
Is there any way to change the order?

```
self.sendDataAndClick = function(data){
    self.setData(data);

    self.showAddModal();
};

//gets the info from the orders vm
shouter.subscribe(function(data) {
    self.setData(data);
}, this, "selectedOrder");

//sets the data for the viewmodel
self.setData = function(data){
    self.equipmentNumber(data.equipment_id());
    self.leg(data);
    self.setSeals(data);
}
```

Comment: I've used the [`setTimeout(fn, 0)` construct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful) in situations like this before to ensure that a given subscription runs after all other updates have been done - may work for you too.

Comment: I *think* you're looking at the icon click being processed before it bubbles to the row click. In any case, James' `setTimeout` suggestion is probably the way to go.

Comment: You could use a ko extender, attach it to shouter, overwrite the `notifySubscribers` method to execute a callback after notification completes.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here's my go at it. It might not fully answer your question, but it demonstrates how you can control the order of execution of subscriptions.

```
ko.extenders.queueSubs = function(target, value) {
    var sQueue = []; // subscription queue
    // set up a normal subscription and execute the queue subscriptions in order.
    target.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        sQueue.forEach(function(item, i) {
           sQueue[i](newValue);
        });
    });
    // overwrite the subscribe function of this observable into
    // a function that adds the subscription at a position in the queue
    target.subscribe = function(pos, fn) {
        sQueue.splice(pos, 0, fn);
    };
};
// use: ko.observable().extend({ queueSubs: true });
// queue a sub: ko.observable().subscribe(0, function(value) { alert(value); });
```

See an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/kevinvanlierde/6gsbghbb/